# How do I use APV PDF Viewer

Tags: java, android, pdf, apvpdf

So I want to view PDFs in my app and I've come across APV PDF, but I just can't understand the instructions on how to use it

http://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/Building

**Why isn't it a jar library to download?**

**Why do I have to compile some .so files, why can't I download them?**

I browsed the source and there is a demo application here:

http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/browse/#hg%2Fpdfview

I copied that into eclipse as an Android project and it compiles but I get an error when I run and select a PDF in the compiled app

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: parseFile
```

I understand this has something to do with what I've asked above, so hopefully I'll get some answers.

This probably has something to do with the NDK which I have no experience with.

Comment: For my own benefit. `.jar` are Java librarys. `.so` appear to be C libraries, so if you 'build' the project like the wiki says all you need to do is add the `.so` files into the `/libs` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mind has been expanded!

1) You can't have a Jar as this is C code, so it is going to run in the NDK therefore the equivalent is a `.so` file.

2) I don't know why they don't let you just download an `.so` file *(as well as having the source)*, but it seems this project is just a starter project i.e. you are expected to take the source and modify it. Therefore if you just had a `.so` file you could not do this. Each time you change the source code in `/jni/pdfview2` you have to rerun the script `build-native.sh` and that will recreate your library (`.so`) files for you!

I was getting the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` as the `.so` library I was using was built against a different version of the code than that which the Java file was trying to reference. Therefore my link was un-satisfied!

Hazar!